# Passing selected ListFragment's row item details (Current Tab) to another ListFragment (Next Tab)

Tags: android, listview, tabs

I have two ListFragments loaded in a tab layout. I need to get the selected ListFragment's row item details(Current Tab) in another ListFragment (Next Tab). How can I achieve this? Should I go with setting in Shared Preference or Is there any way I can access the selected List Fragments details from other Tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared preferences are used to store, well, preferences, not program data. Depending on where your `ListFragment` gets its data from and how your application is structured, you may put the data in a bundle and use `fragment.getArguments()` and `fragment.setArguments()`.

Comment: Thanks you. But I have tab inside tab (Nested Tabs)

Answer (score 2):

Send Data from Current selected row : Adapter click

```
               adapter.setClickListener(new HomeAdapter.ClickListener() {

                    @Override

                    public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {

                        Fragment carDetail = new CarDetailFragment();
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        String jsonString = gson.toJson(mListItem.get(position));
                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        args.putString("jsonString", jsonString);
                        Log.e("jsonString", jsonString);
                        carDetail.setArguments(
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(title);
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, carDetail);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**Get Selected data in to another Fragment....**

**put below code in to onCreateView method..**

```
   String jsonString = getArguments().getString("jsonString", " ");

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Log.e("CAR DETAIL", jsonString);

    obj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, HomeList.class);
```